# Unitary involutions on a simple central algebra after a scalar extension

Tags: nt.number-theory, descent, brauer-groups, involutions, central-simple-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator{id}{id}$
Let $L/K$ be a quadratic separable extension of fields. Let $A$ be a central simple algebra over $L$ such that its norm $N_{L/K}(A)$ splits. Then we know that there exist unitary $L/K$-involutions on $A$ (i.e. involutions of the second kind leaving $K$ element-wise invariant). Given a field extension $K_v/K$, denote by $L_v:=L\otimes K_v$. Every unitary $L/K$-involution $\tau$ on $A$ induces by scalar extension a unitary $L_v/K_v$-involution on $A\otimes K_v$ given by $\tau\otimes\id$. Now my question is, when does a unitary $L_v/K_v$-involution on $A\otimes K_v$ come from a unitary $L/K$-involution on $A$ by scalar extension?

(If you want more details of the kinds of fields I look at: I am interested in the function field $K$ of a $p$-adic curve, and $K_v$ the completion of $K$ with respect to the valuation given by a closed point $v$ on the curve, and $L_v/K_v$ is supposed to be unramified. Also, the index of $A$ is supposed to be $\geq3$.)

In "The Book of Involutions" by Knus, Merkurjev, Rost and Tignol, I found  (3.17) and (3.19) giving a correspondence between unitary $L/K$-involutions on $A$ and the right ideals $I\subset N_{L/K}(A)$ such that $^\iota A\otimes_L A=I_L\oplus(1\otimes A)$, but I don't know if this can be useful.

In the same book, by (2.18), we know that every unitary $L_v/K_v$-involution $
\tau^\prime$ on $A\otimes K_v$ differs from a certain $\tau\otimes\id$ by an inner automorphism defined by $u\in (A\otimes K_v)^\times$, and this $u$ is uniquely determined up to a factor in $K_v^\times$. Now the question becomes: when can we choose $u$ to be from $A^\times$?

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in Corollary 4 of the paper

https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2016.1233188?journalCode=lagb20

Comment: Reference info: Oliver Villa, Conjugation of elements in central simple algebras, Communications in Algebra 45 (5), p2047-2051, 2017. [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1080/00927872.2016.1233188). (Unfortunately all this is behind paywall.)